# Force refresh of VueTable2 on child component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-tables-2

I have a customer component, and inside of it there is a child component with a vuetable 2. What I need to do is to refresh the table, when I update or create a new customer on parent component.

I was looking to use $emit on parent:

```
this.$emit('CustomerInform');
```

In vuetable2 component:

```
this.$on('CustomerInform', () => {
   this.$refs.CustomersTable.refresh();
});
```

When the table was in the same componen where I made the POST/PUT with "$refs.CustomersTable.refresh()" all was working fine...

Comment: Are you trying to $emit from parent and listen for the event on the child? $emit is meant from child -> parent communication not the other way around

Comment: @AndreiSavin yes, that's the problem. But, What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to put a [ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) on the child component inside the parent:

```
<customers-table ref="table" />
```

Then, you will have access to its methods and attributes inside the parent, so you could simply do:

```
this.$refs.table.$refs.CustomersTable.refresh()
```

Another way to do it, is to use a global [event bus](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/).

EventBus.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
export const EventBus = new Vue();
```

Parent:

```
import { EventBus } from EventBus

// ...

EventBus.$emit('CustomerInform')
```

Child:

```
import { EventBus } from EventBus

// ...

created () {
     EventBus.$on('CustomerInform', () => {
        this.$refs.CustomersTable.refresh();
     });
}
```